# python dictionary - list of lists to dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to take list of lists and convert in to dictionary. See code below

```
yearend = [['empl','rating1','rating2','rating3'],['mike','4','4','5'],   
['sam','3','2','5'],['doug','5','5','5']]      
extract the employee names 
employee = [item[0] for item in yearend] #select 1st item from each list  
employee.pop(0) # pop out the empl  
print(employee)  
### output##################################################  
##['mike', 'sam', 'doug']###################################  
###Output###################################################  
###extract the various rating types   
yearend1 = yearend [:] # make a copy  
rating = yearend1.pop(0) # Pop out the 1st list  
rating.pop(0)  
print(rating)  
### output##################################################  
##['rating1', 'rating2', 'rating3']#########################  
###Output###################################################  
# pick employee and rating and convert rating to numeric  
empl_rating = {t[0]:t[1:] for t in yearend1}  
for key,value in empl_rating.items():  
value = list(map(int, value))   
empl_rating[key] = value  
print(empl_rating)  
### output##################################################  
##{'mike': [4, 4, 5], 'sam': [3, 2, 5], 'doug': [5, 5, 5]}##  
###Output###################################################
```

I extracted the data like above and now Iam trying to put together in to dict (New_dicts) so that when

```
New_dicts['sam']['rating1']
```

I get 3 or

```
New_dicts['doug']['rating3']
```

I get 5. What I'm struggling is how to put this data together?

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
def todict(ratings) :
    a ={} 
    a["rating1"] = ratings [0]
    a["rating2"] = ratings [1]
    a["rating3"] = ratings [2]
    return a
```

One way to solve your problem is to get rid of the first row with the headings then just do:
`{item[0] : todict(item[1:]) 
         for item in your_list}`

BTW this sol is based of off how you wanted to index it. I'm sure there is a more generic sol out there.

Because what you want is essentially just a nested dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
New_dicts = {line[0]: {yearend[0][i + 1]: int(rating) for i, rating in enumerate(line[1:])} for line in yearend[1:]}
```